# Trying to create a program that picks 7 digits and tries it on the lottery, is there any easier way to do this?

Tags: java, if-statement

I want to code a program that can basically take 7 "quick pick" randomly generated numbers, and 7 winning numbers and keep looping it over and over again until it hits and counts the number of loops it did before it hit. I can't figure out an easier way to check if each number matches up with a winning number without spending an hour or two writing if statements for each scenario. Here's my code:

```
class chancesofLotterywin {
  
  public static void main(String[] args){
    
    //Quick Pick
    double qp1 = 1;
    double qp2 = 1;
    double qp3 = 1;
    double qp4 = 1;
    double qp5 = 1;
    double qp6 = 1;
    double qp7 = 1;
    
    //Winning Numbers
    double win1 = 1;
    double win2 = 1;
    double win3 = 1;
    double win4 = 1;
    double win5 = 1;
    double win6 = 1;
    double win7 = 1;
   
    for(int i = 0;;i++){
      
      qp1 = Math.floor((Math.random()*50)+1);
      qp2 = Math.floor((Math.random()*50)+1);
      qp3 = Math.floor((Math.random()*50)+1);
      qp4 = Math.floor((Math.random()*50)+1);
      qp5 = Math.floor((Math.random()*50)+1);
      qp6 = Math.floor((Math.random()*50)+1);
      qp7 = Math.floor((Math.random()*50)+1);
      
      win1 = Math.floor((Math.random()*50)+1);
      win2 = Math.floor((Math.random()*50)+1);
      win3 = Math.floor((Math.random()*50)+1);
      win4 = Math.floor((Math.random()*50)+1);
      win5 = Math.floor((Math.random()*50)+1);
      win6 = Math.floor((Math.random()*50)+1);
      win7 = Math.floor((Math.random()*50)+1);
      
      
      if (qp1 == win1){
        if (qp2 == win2){
          if (qp3 == win3){
            if (qp4 == win4){
              if (qp5 == win5){
                if (qp6 == win6){
                  if(qp7 == win7){
                    System.out.println(qp1 + " " + qp2 + " " + qp3 + " " + qp4 + " " + qp5 + " " + qp6 + " " + qp7);
                    System.out.println(win1 + " " + win2  + " " + win3 + " " + win4  + " " + win5 + " " + win6 + " " + win7 );
                    System.out.println(i);
                    break;
                  }else{}
                }else if(qp6 == win7){
                  if(qp7 == win6){
                  System.out.println(qp1 + " " + qp2 + " " + qp3 + " " + qp4 + " " + qp5 + " " + qp6 + " " + qp7);
                  System.out.println(win1 + " " + win2  + " " + win3 + " " + win4  + " " + win5 + " " + win6 + " " + win7 );
                  System.out.println(i);
                  break;
                }else{}
                }else{}
              }else if (qp5 == win6){
                if (qp6 == win5){
                
              }else if (qp5 == win7){
                
              }else{}
            }else if (qp4 == win5){
              
            }else if (qp4 == win6){
              
            }else if (qp4 == win7){
              
            }else{}
          }else if (qp3 == win4){
            
          }else if (qp3 == win5){
            
          }else if (qp3 == win6){
            
          }else if (qp3 == win7){
            
          }else{}
        }else if (qp2 == win3){
          
        }else if (qp2 == win4){
          
        }else if (qp2 == win5){
          
        }else if (qp2 == win6){
          
        }else if (qp2 == win7){
          
        }else{}
      }else if(qp1 == win2){
        
      }else if (qp1 == win3){
        
      }else if (qp1 == win4){
        
      }else if (qp1 == win5){
        
      }else if (qp1 == win6){
        
      }else if (qp1 == win7){
        
      }else{}
        /*if (((qp2 == win1) || (qp2 == win2) || (qp2 == win3) || (qp2 == win4) || (qp2 == win5) ||(qp2 == win6) || (qp2 == win7))){
          if(((qp3 == win1) || (qp3 == win2) || (qp3 == win3) || (qp3 == win4) || (qp3 == win5) ||(qp3 == win6) || (qp3 == win7))){
            if(((qp4 == win1) || (qp4 == win2) || (qp4 == win3) || (qp4 == win4) || (qp4 == win5) ||(qp4 == win6) || (qp4 == win7))){
              if(((qp5 == win1) || (qp5 == win2) || (qp5 == win3) || (qp5 == win4) || (qp5 == win5) ||(qp5 == win6) || (qp5 == win7))){
                if(((qp6 == win1) || (qp6 == win2) || (qp6 == win3 || (qp6 == win4) || (qp6 == win5) ||(qp6 == win6) || (qp6 == win7)))){
                  if(((qp7 == win1) || (qp7 == win2) || (qp7 == win3) || (qp7 == win4) || (qp7 == win5) ||(qp7 == win6) || (qp7 == win7))){
                    System.out.println("check 7");
                    System.out.println(qp1 + " " + qp2 + " " + qp3 + " " + qp4 + " " + qp5 + " " + qp6 + " " + qp7);
                    System.out.println(win1 + " " + win2  + " " + win3 + " " + win4  + " " + win5 + " " + win6 + " " + win7 );
                    System.out.println(i);
                    break;
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }*/
      }
    }
  }
}
```

A lot of it is incomplete because I can't be asked to code every scenario. The commented part out is my previous solution, but it has a problem of having 1 winning number equaling multiple quick pick numbers.

Is there any easier way of doing this? Also please go light on the technical mumbo jumbo, the most I've relearned Java up to was do/while loops.

Comment: Use Arrays or Lists ?

Comment: Put the  quick pick numbers in one list, the winning numbers in another list, then you can get the matching numbers using `quickpicks.retainAll(winning);`

Comment: Note that your random numbers don't guarantee not choosing the same number twice. You can pick 7 distinct numbers by putting 1..50 in a list, shuffling it, then taking the first 7 items.

Comment: I can't get what you are trying to achieve. Why not just compare qp1 == win1 && qp2 == win2 && ... && qp7 == win7? Please provide some examples

Answer (score 0):

```
public class Main {
    private static final Random random = new Random();

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        final var actual = listWithRandomNumbers();
        for(int i = 0;;i++){
            final var guess = listWithRandomNumbers();
            //System.out.println(guess+" | "+actual);
            if(guess.equals(actual)){
                System.out.println(i);
                break;
            }
        }

    }

    private static Set<Integer> listWithRandomNumbers() {
        return Stream.generate(() -> random.nextInt(50) + 1)
                .distinct()
                .limit(7)
                .collect(Collectors.toSet());
    }
}
```

If Streams scare you

```
private static Set<Integer> listWithRandomNumbers() {
        final var set = new HashSet<Integer>(7);
        for (int i = 0; i < 7; i++) {
            while(true){
                final var randomNumber = Main.random.nextInt(50) + 1;
                if(!set.contains(randomNumber)){
                    set.add(randomNumber);
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        return set;
    }
```

or

```
private static Set<Integer> listWithRandomNumbers() {
        final var set = new HashSet<Integer>(7);
        while(true){
            final var randomNumber = random.nextInt(50) + 1;
            set.add(randomNumber);
            if(set.size() == 7){
                break;
            }
        }
        
        return set;
    }
```

Comment: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/set-in-java/ if you want to know more about Sets